# Is color perception of an celestial object effected by red shifting?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, gravitational-redshift

Assuming I stand on the edge of the gravitational well formed by our Sun.

If I was to move infinitely closer to the Sun- and was staring at it without a filter (and wasn't harmed in doing so)- would I go through the color spectrum from white (at the edge) to violet? Would this phenomenon be because of gravitational red-shifting, where the distortion of gravity, relativity to the object, causes wave lengths to expand, thus changing it's frequency?

Answer (score 0):

A gravitational well doesn't have an edge, the gravitational potential created by the Sun is smooth and extends to the infinity, reaching 0 only assymptotically. If you move in this potrntial, the differences in the potential will cause the shift in the observed spectrum of the light, but the shift is gradual.

This can be most easily explained as photons needing to spend some of their enrgy to climb out of the well, thus reducing their frequency and wavelength. But this can equivalently be seen as the effect of gravitational time dilation.

As you appoach the Sun it will never become more violet than what is emitted from the surface of the Sun which is white. As you move away, it will only get redder but not very significantly, because the radius of Sun is much bigger than its Schwarzschild radius - on abolute scale, there isn't that much difference in gravitational potential between the surface of the Sun and spatial infinity.